# Can't import a class - import error

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

My app looks like this:

```
myproject
  - my_app1
  -- lib
  --- my_module1
  ---- __init__.py
  ---- file1.py
  ---- file2.py
  ---- file3.py

  -- views.py
```

In `lib/my_module1.file1.py`

```
  class MyClass1(...):.....
```

And this gives me an import error:

In `views.py` I have:

```
  from my_module1.file1 import MyClass1 #Not found
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `__init__.py` into the `lib` directory.

Also I suspect that you should import like this:

```
from my_app1.lib.my_module1.file1 import MyClass1
```

Comment: Nope.  And use english, please.

Comment: Не могу handle my эмоции.  Ну, тогда ладно. Your approach isn't working - still not found.

Comment: What the exact error you get?  Show the full stack-trace, please.